# OpenJPA Connection error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, openjpa

I am following this tutorial on OpenJPA -> http://plunchete.wordpress.com/2007/05/06/using-openjpa/

I am getting this error :

```
160  INFO   [main] openjpa.Runtime - OpenJPA dynamically loaded the class enhancer. Any classes that were not enhanced at build time will be enhanced when they are loaded by the JVM.
188  INFO   [main] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 2.2.1
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.2.1-r422266:1396819 fatal user error
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: A JDBC Driver or DataSource class
name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property. Available properties in
configuration are "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl@442ce698".
at
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.newDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:72)
```

Persistence.xml is like this :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="example" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
</provider>
<class>Person</class>
<properties>
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema" />
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cs5200" /
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="root" />
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="" />
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Anyone has any idea about this ?

Comment: Can you share your persistence.xml with us?

Comment: I am writing from China at the moment and do not have the access to wordpress :)

Comment: @jedrus07 I have added it now

Comment: It looks like you may not have the required- com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. Are you including this in your POM file (given that this is a maven project)? The required entry would be: <dependency>
 <groupId>mysql</groupId>
 <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
 <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I have added mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar in the classpath

Comment: I am just learning JPA using OpenJPA now...by following tutorials

Comment: The problem is either with persistence.xml not being seen, or the driver not beeing seen. You need to have your persistence.xml in a specific place in your project. Also- if you are not using maven- I strongly recommend it. It is easy to learn (especially if you are using NetBeans or Eclipse) and about the most useful thing for Java.

Comment: Project folder structure is like - > Project -> src,lib,bin,meta-inf. And persistence.xml is inside meta-inf. I included meta-inf in the classpath in eclipse. Yes i think meta-inf is not seen. because even if i delete all the content from it, it shows the same error.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake was the folder structure was wrong.

META-INF should have been inside src folder.

It was not like that. I researched and tested different things and came up with this solution.

I hope it will be helpful to someone in future.

Comment: I was about to comment on that. Glad that you found your solution! - Don't forget to accept your own answer!